# subquery instead of having clause using Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, subquery, aggregate-functions, slick-3.0

How can I express the following subquery in Slick **without** a `HAVING` clause?:

```sql
select team, min_count
from (
    select team, count(min) as min_count
    from table
    group by team
) t
where count > 500
```

[Following the documented approach](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql-to-slick.html#having), `groupBy` followed by `filter` and `map` will cause `HAVING`:

```sql
select team, count(min) as min_count
from table
group by team
HAVING count(min) > 500
```

The reason for preferring a [subquery](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql-to-slick.html#subquery) is to avoid repeating the aggregate outside the `select`.

Comment: "*is to avoid repeating the aggregate*" - if you assume that this improves performance, you are wrong. The aggregate in the having clause is **not** evaluated again in addition to the one in the select list.

Comment: No actually, no concern for performance. Concern is succinctness. I log my queries and would like easier record keeping. Especially with many aggregates (using conditional expressions) it gets ugly quick. Also just a genuine curiosity if Slick can do it without using Plain SQL queries.